Helm Index does not use default value
So below is the code that I am using. I want to use the productName to get the values from productNameReplicas
  replicas: {{ index .Values.productNameReplicas .Values.productName | default 1 }}

Here is my values file
productNameReplicas:
  carAi: 3
  langAI: 3
productName: bookAi

The problem is if the productName is not in productNameReplicas, it doesnt just use the default value and give me the error:
 error calling index: index of untyped nil

Any ideas to get something like this working?

You would get
error calling index: index of untyped nil

when productNameReplicas does not exist in Values.
If productNameReplicas exists in Values but productName does not, then you get:
error calling index: value is nil; should be of type string

For fixing this I would add a default "empty" value for productName. Making my values.yaml as:
productName: ""

productNameReplicas:
  carAi: 3
  langAI: 3


Sorry when copying the values files it didnt include the productName. I have added it. The problem occures when the productName is not found in productNameReplicas

Could you send me the version of your helm binary, please? It seems I have a different behaviour than yours. Mine is v3.10.2 btw.
Could the error be unrelated to what you've shared above? Maybe if you share your helm chart templates I could have a better understanding on what fails in your case. I mean, could it be another part in your templates that causes this error you're getting?
